# Laptop can only see a couple of networks

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a new Lenovo T540p that can see, connect to and use the networks created by my router, but can not see the networks created by other routers.

If I walk away from my router (outside), I lose the link and the laptop says that no connections are available. My phone, placed right next to the laptop, can see 10+ connection options from neighbors. When I walk back to my router, the laptop auto connects to the network again.

I have tried removing my WiFi driver and reinstalling it, as well as installing  updates from Lenovo System update.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: The metal case of the laptop might be blocking the signal of access points.

Comment: @Burgi, Thanks but the case is plastic

Comment: @David While some of the panels are plastic, the frame on these is made of Magnesium. But more towards your problem, It's probably worth testing with a bootable USB OS to verify if the issue is hardware or software related.

Comment: I had the same issue on a windows 10 laptop that could see several of my neighbor's wireless networks but none of the networks from my much closer Omada router (regardless of whether it was 2.4GHz, 5GHz, dual-band).  I eventually solved it by [updating the driver for the network card](https://superuser.com/a/1708596/63843), by connecting to the internet some other way, going to "Device Manager" -> "Network Adapters" -> Click on name of NIC (for me it was "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265").  Go over to Drivers tab and select "Update Driver" and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Your laptop has a 2.4GHz-only Wi-Fi card, but your phone is dual-band (2.4 and 5GHz), so your phone sees 5GHz networks that your laptop can't.
- Even if both support the same bands, maybe your laptop supports a different set of Wi-Fi channels than your phone does. Maybe your phone and laptop were designed for different countries. For example, Europe allows channels 1-13 in 2.4GHz, but the USA only allows 1-11. The USA and Europe also have different 5GHz channels that each supports or doesn't support.
- Your laptop's Wi-Fi antennas aren't connected correctly or are damaged, so it can only see networks it's very close to.
- Maybe your laptop Wi-Fi UI chooses not to show you Wi-Fi networks whose signal strength is so low that you can't get a good connection, whereas your smartphone OS shows you everything, even stuff you'd most likely fail to connect to because the signal is extremely weak.

Comment: "Your laptop's Wi-Fi antennas aren't connected correctly or are damaged" It was this one. Thank you!

Comment: @David Thanks for the followup. It's always nice to know I've helped.