# Wi-Fi access point is invisible to one laptop, but visible to others. Why/How?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop

What could cause the Wi-Fi access point to be invisible to one computer, but visible to others?

A client of mine has a Windows 10 laptop that cannot see her router’s access point.

The access point is visible and works fine for all other devices in the home.  The laptop can see and connect to any other access point when she travels, and also connects to my mobile hotspot without issue.

**What I have tried:**

- Placing the laptop right next to the router
- Disabling antivirus software and Windows Firewall
- Full network reset on the laptop
- Factory reset of the modem/router
- Using an external Wi-Fi dongle on the laptop
- Verify the WiFi *range* of the laptop (I was able to see my car's cloud cameras from way out on the street)

I have run out of things to test.  A new access point would work, but I’m baffled as to what is the exact cause.

**Edit:**  This issue isn't similar to [Laptop can only see a couple of networks](https://superuser.com/questions/1070130/laptop-can-only-see-a-couple-of-networks) because in this case, the laptop does connect to other access points from the same region (AU). And the router has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands, but the laptop sees neither.  All of the suggested points in the accepted answer have already been ruled out by *What I have tried* above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop can only see a couple of networks](https://superuser.com/questions/1070130/laptop-can-only-see-a-couple-of-networks)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, no.  It connects to other access points from the same region (AU).  And the router has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands, but the laptop sees neither.

Comment: Regardless, what frequency (channel) is the access point at? Regions are not exclusive -- for 2.4 GHz band, all of them share the first 11 channels, so an US device would still be able to connect to e.g. an EU device on channel 6 or 9, just wouldn't see one that's on channel 13.

Comment: @user1686, interesting, thanks.  But if the laptop were using channel 13 would it still be able to connect to other devices using only the first 11 channels?  Also, after a Network Reset on Windows and a factory reset on the router, they'd surely both just be using those first 11 channels right?

Comment: @user1686, I will have to return and check what channel the AP is using, but it's a safe bet it's nothing custom as I reset the device.  It's a standard Telstra issued modem.  I'll look it up and see if I can find out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether it is on the block list.

`netsh wlan show filters permission=block`

If yes, remove from block list

`netsh wlan delete filter permission=block ssid="Your SSID" networktype=infrastructure`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are broadcasting 5Ghz frequency and only one device with compatible receiver is able to view the network SSID

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me with a Win 10 Vaio laptop (with "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265" NIC) that could not connect to any wifi network from my Omada AC access point, but could connect to my phone's mobile hotspot (and see a bunch of networks).  I tried several things that didn't work:

- search for [network filters above](https://superuser.com/a/1580932/63843),
- go through windows updates,
- reboot several times,
- created a couple new access point under different names in different configurations (dual-band, just 2.4 GHz, just 5.0GHz, guest network, force to use non-troublesome channel, etc.),
- try after (temporarily) disabling firewall/virus protection,

What finally worked was to update the driver for my NIC.  So first connect to my mobile hotspot for internet access, then go to "Device Manager" -> "Network Adapters" -> (select network adapter, which for me was "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265").  Then open up the "Driver" tab and select "Update Driver" (which went online to look for an updated driver which it installed).  Apparently, updating to the Dec 2018 version of the driver (from the 2017 version) fixed the issue.